# Drupal 8 Enity Print how get node id from the url

Tags: printing, drupal, module, entity

I've set up entity print to print my article or page as pdf. I am using wkthmltodpdf library and the pdf is generating as expected. But I can’t get the header or footer to print on each pdf page. Also, I can’t get the tittle or heading of the article to print in each header of the pdf page.

And I am trying to get the title or heading of the article by the **node id** and I don’t how this works. I have built preprocess and static functions below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public static function buildEntityPrint($node) {
    if (is_numeric($node)) {
      $node = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->load($node);
    }

    $publication = self::getPublicationOrChapterNode($node);
    $top_bid = $publication->book['bid'];
    if (!empty($top_bid)) {
      $publication = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->load($top_bid);
    }

    $markup = $publication->toLink()->toString();
    return $markup;
  }



___________ preprocessor____________

function pubsite_preprocess_entity_print(&$variables) {

 $alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $params = Url::fromUri("internal:" . $alias)->getRouteParameters();
  if (!empty($params['node']) && is_numeric($params['node'])) {

    $node = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->load($params['node']);

    $variables['entityPrintVar'] = NavigationHelper::buildEntityPrint($node);
  }
}
```